# JavaScript function in external HTML file not invoked when an object is passed as parameter from an Angular2 component

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, angular

I am using Angular2 for a mobile app and I have to open a URL in a new window using one of the inbuilt cordova plugins (InAppBrowser). To detect the event upon which the page-loading of the new window completes, there is an EventListener "loadstop" as given below. This is from a component inside my app

```
var options = {url: "mylink", fileName: "myfilename"};    
let browser = new InAppBrowser('http://www.myexamplesite.com', '_blank', 'location=no');
browser.on("loadstop")
      .subscribe(
      () => {
        browser.executeScript(
          {
            code: "getOptions("+options+");"
          });
      },
      err => {
        console.log("Loadstop Event Error: " + err);
      });
```

The external URL is a HTML file with some JavaScript code. The **getOptions(options)** is a JavaScript function defined there as inline. This is the function:

```
function getOptions(options) {
     alert("Values are "+options['url']+" and "+options['name']);
}
```

But the function is not invoked in this way. It works when I remove the parameter **options** from both the call and the definition. What could be the reason? Are the objects in Angular2 and JavaScript not interoperable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way you are concatenating the string and `options`. You could use `JSON.stringify` to get something you can concatenate.

Illustration of the issue:

```
var options = {url: "mylink", fileName: "myfilename"};   


// This is what you do:
console.log("getOptions("+options+");");

// This is what you should do:
console.log("getOptions(" + JSON.stringify(options) + ");");

//
// This shows it works: `getOptions` will be called.
//
function getOptions(options) {
    console.log("OPTIONS: ", options);
    console.log("Values are "+options['url']+" and "+options['fileName']);    
}

eval("getOptions(" + JSON.stringify(options) + ");");
```

If you run the above, you get this on the console:

```
getOptions([object Object]);
getOptions({"url":"mylink","fileName":"myfilename"});
OPTIONS:  { url: 'mylink', fileName: 'myfilename' }
Values are mylink and myfilename
```